# Appium) Finishing setting up optional dependencies

Tags: appium

First of all, below is required information.

```
OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.2
Node: 10.13.0
AndroidStudio: 3.1.4
```

When I run appium doctor, I'am getting two optional dependencies are missing.

```
1. `opencv4nodejs`
2. `bundletool.jar`
```

If I try to install `opencv4nodejs`, but I got warning:

```
opencv4nodejs@4.14.0 has no binaries
```

(It seems like auto build failed)

And I have no idea how to add export `bundletool.jar` as PATH.

Comment: Thanks! Finally, the good appium-doctor gave me a clean bill of health.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just ran into this myself. Installing opencv4nodejs was pretty easy - for that, I used:

```
npm -g install opencv4nodejs
```

There may have been dependencies of 'opencv4nodejs' that I had to install - I can't remember; that may have required me to install 'make' with *brew install make*

The hard one was the bundletool.jar - here are the steps I followed for that:

1. Searched for 'bundletool.jar' and found a place to download it from Google - I got 'bundletool-all-0.8.0.jar' from https://github.com/google/bundletool/releases
2. I renamed this file to just 'bundletool.jar' and placed in my Android SDK folder, under its own sub-folder called 'bundle-tool' - full path: /Users/{USER}/Library/Developer/Android/sdk/bundle-tool
3. I had to make the bundletool.jar executable with:

   chmod +x bundletool.jar
4. Added the 'bundle-tool' folder to Path with the following addition in my ~/.bashrc file:

   PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/bundle-tool"
5. Now running *which 'bundletool.jar'* is happy and finds it in the 'bundle-tool' folder I created (see step 2)
6. Running 'appium-doctor' is now satisfied - and doesn't report any missing dependencies.

Hope that helps.

2019-10-31 update:

With MacOS Catalina (specifically 10.15.1) - I ran into a problem with installing *opencv4nodejs* using the npm command shown above.  Opencv4nodejs wants to be built - but using C++ 11 features (from what I read) and has a problem with *constexpr* on MacOS.  So, I first installed OpenCV with Brew - using *brew install opencv@4* and then had to set the environment variable to not autobuild OpenCV with *export OPENCV4NODEJS_DISABLE_AUTOBUILD=1*
Then I was able to install opencv4nodejs with the npm command shown above - and appium-doctor shows that its dependencies are in place.

Comment: This was very helpful for the "bundletool" part! Thanks